# How do I hover or dropright to display my list in the same column without crossing the border?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a grid with 3 col-md-4. in the first column I have a list of 9 elements - x, y, z, etc. I want hover or dropright to x to appear in the second column 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, at y to appear 10,11,12 and so on but not to exceed the edges of the second column and all the lists appear on the hover at x, y, z to appear in the same position.
I also want the grid to appear in the middle of the screen

Comment: Have you tried before asking this question ?

Comment: Of course. You want the code?

Comment: your code and your error message or unexpected output

Comment: https://codepen.io/msoficaru/pen/eodQPR